# how to split the loop result in python with same name

Tags: python-3.x

I want split the loop results but unable to find best solution in python

```
a = [sep2020, oct2020, nov2020, dec2020]
for i in a;
    print(i)
```

result will be,

```
sep2020
oct2020
nov2020
dec2020
```

Comment: can you tell us what you mean  " split the loop results" what Output are you expecting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your question.

Comment: You have a typo: the `for` line should end with a `:` and not a `;`.

Comment: split the looping results while calling same variable like 'i'. for example if i print(i) it produce sep2020, oct2020, nov2020, dec2020 in a list. but i want split the result. example if i print(i[0]) - produce it will give 'sep' only. not fully sep2020. how to split the results in loop. pls guide me

Comment: Lookup string indexing and slicing: `print(i[:3])`

Comment: Thanks Johny it produce output as what i expect. suppose if the result like sep.2020 something like that. how could i slice it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the required output just by slicing i directly because the length of month names would always be 3, like this:

```py
a = [sep2020, oct2020, nov2020, dec2020]
for i in a:
    a,b=i[0:3],i[3::]
    print(a,b)
```

Splitting i as you wanted is not possible as there is nothing that can be a separator between month names and years

Comment: @PoovendranAlagarsamy `result=i.split(".")` might help you, where `result[0]` and `result[1]` is what you want